# Direct Mode Import available for Teradata SQOOP import?

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

Is there direct mode import available for teradata sqoop import? I'm not able find any reference in the documentation below.
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html
http://archive.cloudera.com/docs-backup/sqoop/_direct_mode_imports.html

please help

Comment: There is a Teradata Sqoop connector for Cloudera :  [Clicky!](http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/sqoop/teradata/1-2c5.html).

Comment: Cloudera's Connector for Teradata uses JDBC FastLoad and FastExport API's to move data between the platforms. This may not be as fast as native CLI based FastLoad and FastExport or TPT, but it should outperform row-by-row movement of data. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Andrew and Rob!

Answer (score 0):

This is from same version of [SqoopUserGuide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases) that you have linked in your question.

[image: Supported Databases]

Comment: Thanks BDL..Needed to know if available for TD. I guess this option is vendor specific and not available.